# Why my navigation container not has the same height as logo and search container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm doing some practise with `flexbox` because I want to know how it works and how is to work without using floats, display inline or block and so on, but I'm having a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I have the header section with three containers: logo, navigation links and search. The container for the logo and the search have the same height (104px) but the navigation container no (41px).

Here's my current code, I added a background-color to the elements to show the height difference. I would like to know if there's a way to make the naviation container get the same height as the others (104px).

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* reset styles */

body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* main wrappers */

.page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  padding: 10px 2%;
}
/* header styles */

header {
  display: flex;
}
header .header-logo,
header .header-search-npt {
  width: 20%;
}
header .header-logo {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
header .navigation-links {
  width: 60%;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
header .navigation-links ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
header .navigation-links ul li {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
header .navigation-links ul a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header .header-search-npt {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
header .header-search-npt input {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <section class="header">

    <header>

      <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=18&txt=100x100&w=100&h=100" alt="the logo">
      </div>
      <div class="navigation-links">

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
      <div class="header-search-npt">
        <input type="search" name="search-btn" placeholder="Search..." />
      </div>

    </header>

  </section>

</div>
```

I think there should be a solution without specifying a height for the container because I will try to make responsive the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that flexbox is able to provide equal height columns by default is that the [**`align-items`** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) is set to `stretch` by default.

In your code, you have overridden the default setting for the nav links with `align-self: center`:

```
header .navigation-links {
    width: 60%;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

In order to restore the flex item to equal height with its siblings, you need to remove that line of code (or make it `align-self: stretch`).

```
header .navigation-links {
    width: 60%;
    /* align-self: center; <-- REMOVE */
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mvwud6/)

Then, if you want to center the nav links, make `.navigation-links` a nested flex container and center its flex items:

```
header .navigation-links {
    width: 60%;
    /* align-self: center; <-- REMOVE */
    background-color: deepskyblue;

    /* NEW */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mvwud6/1/)

Then, to restore equal height to the first column (the logo), remove the top and bottom margins:

```
header .header-logo {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    /* margin: 10px 0; <-- REMOVE */
    }
```

[**DEMO 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mvwud6/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the demos, now I understand a bit more how flexbox works.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I gather you want to make the logo, navigation and search divs the same height. It looks like your margin style on your header .header-logo CSS is offsetting them. Try removing the margin from your logo and they should line up evenly.

From:

```
header .header-logo {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

To:

```
header .header-logo {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

Then add a height to your navigation links style.

From:

```
header .navigation-links {
  width: 60%;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

To:

```
header .navigation-links {
  width: 60%;
  height:104px;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```